# Count number of unique values in a column, restricted by two other columns' criteria

Tags: excel

I have a rather large data dump used in my analysis.

Here is a small example of a part of the data I am working with.

[image: Example]

What I am trying to is count how many unique serial numbers there are for a specific location (six flags) for a specific model (4250).

I was originally trying to apply a SUMPRODUCT divided by a COUNTIF statement that I found from another example with no success. I have found plenty of documentation on how to calculate frequencies, but nothing on having restrictions from two other column values.

Comment: (Instead of a screen shot, can you copy/paste the data here and format as a table, the code tags should work (`{}`), thanks!)

Comment: Did you try COUNTIFS or a pivot table?

Comment: BruceWayne, thanks for letting me know. I am new to submitting to this site.

Jan, I did try COUNTIFS and was having trouble getting it to work when limited by the location and model columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SUMPRODUCT/COUNTIFS formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A$2:A$17=E2)*(B$2:B$17=F2))/(COUNTIFS(C$2:C$17, C$2:C$17, A$2:A$17, E2, B$2:B$17, F2)+(A$2:A$17<>E2)+(B$2:B$17<>F2)))
```

[image]

The ranges should be kept to the minimum number of rows of actual data. To make these ranges dynamic you need to change all occurrences of A2:A17, B2:B17 & C2:C17 to,

```
'A2:A17
A$2:index(a:a, match("zzz", a:a))
'B2:B17
B$2:index(b:b, match("zzz", a:a))
'C2:C17
C$2:index(c:c, match("zzz", a:a))
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I actually got this to work for my needs except for one part the data that I have will change over time.Is there any way that I could make this equation scalable so that I don't have to manually enter the number of total lines in the formula?

Comment: See addendum added above.

Answer (score 1):

This is a conditional sum on concatenated contents of your desired criteria, where it only shows the answer for the first instance of the value. Hope this helps!

[SFCF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FouSd.png)